# Add unlimited fields to block module

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm creating a module which adds a block.
In that block, I want users to be able to add as many (text) fields as they need. I know you can set up content-types to allow users to add as many fields as they need, but how can I implement this into a block module?

Long story short: is it possible to add a text field with an unlimited amount of fields to a block (module) the same way it can be done in content types?

Comment: Checkout https://drupal.org/project/bean which lets you add fields to blocks.

Comment: That module makes older blocks unusable for me. A shame really, because it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Node Block](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module.

With this module you can make your block fieldable, like your content-types.

> This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block.
>   This allows the content managers of the site to edit the block text
>   and title without having to access the block administration page.
>   Users only need edit access to that node in order to edit it.

Check out this quick [Demo Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klAZ_Skykk8)

Comment: I want to create a module, which I can use more often. It seems that I have to overwrite a template to be able to get the output of that module, right? That would make it less easy to reuse the module at a later time, or am I missing something?